# Groovy script - Error unmarshaling return

Tags: groovy

I am working on this function:

```
if ( (myFsName != null)  ) {
    try {
        s_log.trace("Process >         >> setAdminGroup > RelCI is Node > FS event > checking FS name is null > NOT null");
        s_log.trace("Process >         >> setAdminGroup > RelCI is Node > FS event > checking FS name is null > NOT null" + relCiID + myFsName + myNodeNameHint);
        String adminGrp = ucmdbCache.get(myNodeNameHint).get(myFsName);
        s_log.trace("Process >         >> setAdminGroup > RelCI is Node > FS event > checking admingrp >" + adminGrp);
        if(adminGrp == null){
            s_log.trace("Process >         >> setAdminGroup > RelCI is Node > FS event > checking ADMIN GROUP is null > IS null");
            adminGrp = dataSHM.get(relCiID).get(adminGroupAttrName); 
        }
        evt.addCustomAttribute (adminGroupCaName,adminGrp);
        s_log.trace("Process >         >> setAdminGroup > RelCI is Node > FS event > Added Custom attribute" + adminGroupCaName + adminGrp);
        return; // nothing else to do
    } catch (Exception e) {
        s_log.error("        >> setAdminGroup > Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
} else {
// if I was not able to extract FS name I don\'t return: fall back to node
}
```

and i got this error:

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access remote service [rmi://localhost:21303/CaScriptingService]; nested exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ENIcallMDC (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled) -- Could not access remote service [rmi://localhost:21303/CaScriptingService]; nested exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ENIcallMDC (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled) -- Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ENIcallMDC (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled) -- ENIcallMDC (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)  
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access remote service [rmi://localhost:21303/CaScriptingService]; nested exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ENIcallMDC (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

I think is related to *return* command, please do you have any suggestion about it?

Thanks with regards,
Fabrizio

Comment: what is ucmdbCache and dataSHM?  How are you using rmi?  There's no sign of it in the code?

Comment: hello, they are both global hashmap setting in same way but into different function's script `dataSHM   = Collections.synchronizedMap(localHM)` and `ucmdbCache = Collections.synchronizedMap(localHM)`. Consider that i am running this script into another application, so ths script has been called inside it. Please let me know if you need further details. Regards, Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

I would like to inform you that i have solved previous error changing largely my script and calculating now *ucmdbCache* hashmap without using an external function but working with it on the main one.

Regards,
Fabrizio